# NaNs after merging two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes like the following:

df1

```
         id         name
-------------------------
0        43          c
1        23          t
2        38          j
3         9          s
```

df2

```
          user        id
--------------------------------------------------
0         222087      27,26
1         1343649     6,47,17
2         404134      18,12,23,22,27,43,38,20,35,1
3         1110200     9,23,2,20,26,47,37
```

I want to split all the ids in df2 into multiple rows and join the resultant dataframe to df1 on "id".

I do the following:

```
b = pd.DataFrame(df2['id'].str.split(',').tolist(), index=df2.user_id).stack()
b = b.reset_index()[[0, 'user_id']] # var1 variable is currently labeled 0
b.columns = ['Item_id', 'user_id']
```

When I try to merge, I get NaNs in the resultant dataframe.

```
pd.merge(b, df1, on = "id", how="left")

              id       user      name
-------------------------------------
0              27      222087     NaN
1              26      222087     NaN
2              6      1343649     NaN
3              47     1343649     NaN
4              17     1343649     NaN
```

So, I tried doing the following:

```
b['name']=np.nan
for i in range(0, len(df1)):
    b['name'][(b['id'] == df1['id'][i])] = df1['name'][i]
```

It still gives the same result as above. I am confused as to what could cause this because I am sure both of them should work!
Any help would be much appreciated!

I read similar posts on SO but none seemed to have a concrete answer. I am also not sure if this is not at all related to coding or not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the issue is that original you had a string and then you split, so you may have incompatible dtypes, try `b = pd.DataFrame(df2['id'].str.split(',').tolist(), index=df2.user_id).stack().astype(int)`

Comment: Yes, it indeed was the issue! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you need convert column `id` in `df2` to `int`, because output of `string` functions is always `string`, also if works with numeric.

```
df2.id = df2.id.astype(int)
```

Another solution is convert `df1.id` to `string`:

```
df1.id = df1.id.astype(str)
```

And get `NaN`s because no match - `str` values doesnt match with `int` values.

Comment: Yes, 6 months ago I cannot find this problem - still NaN and all seems nice. But after 2 hours I find solution - and I always remember it ;)

Comment: haha you are truly awesome! You have solutions to almost all the doubts I have!!