# Python/Pandas - New column based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column, which has to adhere to multiple conditions in multiple places. I have three dataframes:
- The one I'd like to add the column to: `data`

```
ID Timestamp
25 201605252300 #Y/M/D/H/M
29 201605252315
94 201605252015
```

- The one that contains info on data availability: `dataavail`

```
Timestamp    Availability
201605252300 True
201605252315 False
201605252015 True
```

- The one that contains the actual data `weatherdata`

```
ID Timestamp    Precipitation
25 201605252300 1
```

The thing is, that if there is *no* rain, that is *not* marked by `weatherdata.Precipitation` being `0`, but by simply missing from `weatherdata`. However, not all data that is missing means no precipitation, it can also mean technical failure. That's where `dataavail` comes in. If for a `Timestamp` in `data` the `Availability` is `False`, that means there was a technical problem and there's no data. If for a `Timestamp` in `data` the `Availability` is `True`, that means the precipitation was actually 0.

Now, I'd like to combine this info into the `data` field. So:
IF the `Timestamp/ID` pair from `data` exists in `weatherdata`, it should simply pull the info from there.
IF the `Timestamp/ID` pair from `data` DOES NOT exists in `weatherdata`, it should check the `dataavail` dataframe AND IF the `Availability` is `True`, the `Precipitation` should be `0`, otherwise is should be `NA/NaN` so I can impute it later.

So for the above example, the desired output would be

```
ID Timestamp    Precipitation
25 201605252300 1
29 201605252315 NaN
94 201605252015 0
```

What's the syntax to use in such a setup, where mutiple conditions have to be satisfied, based on sub-conditions? Thank you!

**UPDATE**

Tried jezrael's solution. I have the following dataframes:

[image]

[image]

So then I do `mergedAll = pd.merge(imp_df, precip, on=['SId','Time'], how='left')` on them. The result:

[image]

I've checked programatically, and ALL the data in `Intensity` is `NaN`. `dtypes` match:
[image]

**UPDATE 2**

After sorting my data out, the ˙mask˙ part still doesn't work:
[image]

Even though `201311292300,TRUE` is in the availability dataframe, the Intensity gets translated to `NaN` instead of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
#add weatherdata data if exist
df = pd.merge(data, weatherdata, on=['ID','Timestamp'], how='left')

#get Timestamp values where True in column Availability
vals = dataavail.loc[dataavail.Availability, 'Timestamp']
print (vals)
0    201605252300
2    201605252015
Name: Timestamp, dtype: int64

#True if exist Timistamps in vals and if not exist in df (NaN)
mask = df.Timestamp.isin(vals) & df.Precipitation.isnull()
#convert True to 0
df.Precipitation = df.Precipitation.mask(mask, 0)
print (df)
   ID     Timestamp  Precipitation
0  25  201605252300            1.0
1  29  201605252315            NaN
2  94  201605252015            0.0
```

Comment: `df = pd.merge(data, weatherdata, on=['ID','Timestamp'], how='left')` Leaves me with all `NaN` values for the whole `Precipitation` column, any idea why?

Comment: But I only want `NaN` if data is MISSING, but I get `NaN` for EVERY row right now.

Comment: and because use left join - [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra).

Comment: I do use left join... I'll show you, give me a minute.

Comment: I think you get `NaN` because different dtype of columns - e.g. column `ID` in `data` is `int` and  in `weatherdata` it is str

Comment: so need same dtypes - both int or both str

Comment: and `NaN` in output are explain better [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42782023/2901002) - I hope ;)

Comment: Both are `int64` according to `dtypes`

Comment: so `print (imp_df[['SId','Time']].dtypes)` and 
`print (precip[['SId','Time']].dtypes)` are same? all 4?

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been telling you. But I've added a screenshot for you.

Comment: So then only problem can be there is no match for pairs `SId` and `Times`, something is wrong

Comment: one possible solution for check matching is `print (data.set_index(['ID','Timestamp']).index.intersection(weatherdata.set_index(['ID','Timestamp']).index))

`

Comment: I found where the problem was, but the function still doesn't quite work. I'll update the question.

Comment: So `Intensity` is till `NaN` instead of 0 even though it's clear that availability is `True`.

Comment: If use `mymask = mergedAll.Time.isin(vals)` it replace it?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't.

Comment: `mymask = mergedAll.Time.isin(vals).values & mergedAll.Intensity.isnull()` did the trick. Thank you!